# Get name of current view residing in a UIWindow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwindow

Let's say I add a new view to my UIWindow

```
[windowRoot addSubview:MyNewView.view];
```

Is it possible to retrieve the name of that view later on if
I have reference to windowRoot?
Something like:

```
[windowRoot getCurrentViewName]
```

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIWindow` **is** a `UIView`, so you can do something like this to get the subviews of it:

```
for (UIView *view in windowRoot.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"View: %@", view);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to imply a bigger design issue.   I assume by "name" you mean the name of the variable referring to new view?  That variable should actually be an instance variable of your window controller.

Comment: Hi Andy! No I actually want the name of the view, not the instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUserDefaults *savedData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *currentPage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.nibName];

[savedData setObject:currentPage forKey:@"lastViewAccessed"];

//self.nibName will get you what you the name of the view.
```